# AWS EC2 Instance Connection Refused in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am somewhat new to this, so it's possible it's an obvious or dumb fix I have not thought of.

I have a EC2 instance I created with this AMI: ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-20201026. I am using a 2020 Macbook Pro with Big Sur.

When I SSH into the server from my macbook's terminal, either via:

```
ssh -i FirstKeyPair.pem ubuntu@ec2-X-XX-XXX-XX.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

or

```
ssh -i FirstKeyPair.pem ubuntu@X.XX.XXX.XX
```

I have no issues. To see if everything was working, I tried creating an `index.html` file in the root directory with nothing but `hello world` in it. I then ran `PHP -s localhost:3000`

However, when I try to navigate to my public IP `X.XX.XXX.XX:3000`, or `ec2-X-XX-XXX-XX.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000 in my Chrome browser, I get "This site can’t be reached, X.XX.XXX.XX refused to connect, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

I have checked my Security Groups and opened everything, so they look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyJkn.png).

And the same is happening on my outbound rules. I checked that I don't have a firewall on my mac as well. How can I get my PHP server, or just that index.html file, to show up when I navigate to my IP in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running your server on `localhost` which means that it is not accessible on the normal network interfaces.  Try `php -S 0.0.0.0:3000` instead.  This says to listen on all interfaces.  But be careful - this is not a recommended configuration and you should look into putting a real web server (i.e. Apache, nginx, etc.) in front of it.

Comment: Yep I'll switch to another server, I just wanted to understand why I was getting connection refused, but 0.0.0.0:3000 seems to have worked! Thank you!